# Disable contextual filter when exposed filter has value

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In drupal 7 i want to show a view.

For logged in users i want to get a term list from their user profile and show all nodes with this tags.

This i have done by setting the contextual filter with user:id and by default to grab the user id from logged in user.

I do this and now i want this. If i choose from exposed filter a value that is not set in user profile, the view should ignore the contextual filter and show that category. Insteadof this, the view dont display anything because that value is not set in user profile.

Furthermore. if an anonymous user acces page he gets nothing instead of display all content and a exposed filter where he could choose a search improvement.

The ideea is that i want to let user to define some preference settings for showing articles and if they want to view other categories to change it in exposed form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this strictly by configuring the Views module.

I'd do this by making several different views, and then putting them in tabs.

If this doesn't work for you, you're likely looking at building a custom module with a custom search form.

I'd recommend starting with multiple views in tabs and seeing if you need to go further.

http://www.interworks.com/blogs/samaral/2011/12/16/how-add-tabs-drupal-pages